# Ошибка отправки самого простого сообщения в aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, asyncio, aiogram

Мне нужно чтобы сообщения с онлайн чата на моём сайте пересылались мне в телеграм, а мои сообщения в телеграме - в этот онлайн чат. Для этого я создал бота. Проблема с отправкой сообщений в aiogram. Как мне отправить сообщение от бота самому себе? До этого я работал с telebot, там была такая возможность. Можно было создать бота, написать ему что-то и узнать id чата. Далее отправлять сообщения по id чата. В Aiogram же прежде чем что-то отправить нужно получить сообщение (это навязывается во всех примерах в официальной документации). Нашёл метод send_message в документации, пытаюсь его использовать но ничего не выходит.

**Для тех кому лень читать начинать отсюда:**

Код из официальной документации:

```
# Так же сказано, что этот метод принимает 2 обязательных аргумента:
# первый - id чата, второй - текст сообщения
result: Message = await bot.send_message(...)
```

Мой код:

```
from aiogram import Bot
import asyncio


token = '...'
bot = Bot(token=token)


async def send(text):
    await bot.send_message(915422005, text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(send('Привет!'))
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 14, in <module>
    asyncio.run(send('Привет!'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "bot.py", line 10, in send
    await bot.send_message(915422005, text)
  File "/home/dima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 219, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "/home/dima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 201, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/home/dima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 103, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/dima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/dima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 426, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/home/dima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 579, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used '
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f3e5631c460>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
pip3 uninstall aiogram
pip3 install aiohttp
```

Написал свою библиотеку

Comment: Давайте без пони, а?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под "пони"

Comment: [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor я не думаю, что пользователь линукса напишет эту команду себе в терминал, тем более, когда там жирнущим текстом болшущими буквами такое предупреждение

Comment: 1) Предупреждение добавли я. 2) Всякие бывают.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor эту команду можно увидеть где угодно это даже не код. Такая комбинация есть на многих сайтах. Не понимаю почему вы считаете это вредоносным кодом. Если разработчики добавляют это, значит они чем-то руководствуются и я не думаю, что это нужно скрывать. Да предупреждение уместно, соглашусь.

Comment: `Такая комбинация есть на многих сайтах`  — всмысле?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor я имею ввиду, что информация об этой команде в открытом доступе и узнать её можно откуда угодно. Давайте тогда везде выпиливать её и скрывать то, что такое возможно. Многие говорят это в шутку, в том числе и я

Comment: `Если разработчики добавляют это, значит они чем-то руководствуются и я не думаю, что это нужно скрывать` — Разработчики создали команду, которая удаляет файл или папку. Но они даже специально добавили флаг, чтоб не снести / случайно.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ну добавили флаг, а не убрали возможность удаления

Comment: Да шутка то хорошая, в данном случае, но я добавил предупреждение, я не прошу комманду убрать.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor я согласен с вами, что предупреждение уместно, я просто не понял к чему сообщение `Давайте без пони, а?`

Comment: А убрать вообще эту опцию нельзя, а то есть много способов: `rm -rf /*`, `sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sda`, `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda`, `sudo echo "nothing" > /dev/sda` etc.

Comment: Под пони я имел в виду, что без предупреждения.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ну я не проверял, но подозреваю, что флаг нужен будет во всех случаях. Можно же проверять перед удалением, затронет ли это `/`

Comment: Нет. А проверить можешь здесь: https://www.onworks.net/

Comment: @VictorVosMottor убрать то можно, просто будет чуть сложнее чем я предполагал, всё возможно

Answer (score 1):

> RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task

Вы создали бота в другом контексте.

`asyncio.run()` создаёт новую цепочку событий, а при создании объекта `bot` была присвоена другая цепочка. Это и вызвало ошибку.

Для вас было бы решением помещение создания бота в существующий контекст:

```
...

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=token)
    send('Привет!')

async def send(text):
    await bot.send_message(915422005, text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

На данный момент даже в вашем варианте код будет работать после установки последней версии `aiogram`.

В следующий раз перед созданием собственной библиотеки попробуйте поискать возникшую ошибку в Stack overflow.

Comment: Возможно оно сейчас будет работать, но насколько я помню при создании нового `event loop` внутри существующего python выдаёт другую ошибку. Тут ошибка от aiogram не несущая никакой информации, она указывает совсем на другое. В документации ни слова. Не понятно как до этого нужно догадаться. Легче свою библиотеку написать чем сидеть в aiogram вникать и в то, что он делает

Comment: У аиограм дружелюбное русскоязычное сообщество в телеграм, где можно обратиться с существующей проблемой, это в разы быстрее, чем писать подобный фреймворк самому

Comment: Мне легче, чем разбираться в этом

Answer (score 0):

Пример из [документации](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/broadcast_example.py)

```py
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

API_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN HERE'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def somefunc():
    await bot.send_message(123456, "Привет")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start(dp, somefunc())
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это немного не очевидно, что для этого нужно лезть на гитхаб. И я пробовал этот метод, он не работал и выкидывал ошику

Comment: Для разработчиков - очевидно. Если вы пытаетесь им стать - привыкайте :)
Примеры в документации и на github рабочие, только что ещё раз проверил.